# Find the position vector on the curve after moving 10 units from the given starting point

Tags: vector-spaces, curves

An ant moves along a curve **r**(t) = < 3sin(t), 4t, 3cos(t) > where t is time, starting at (0,0,3). Find the position vector on the curve after moving 10 units along the curve from the starting point.

What I know:

-I think I have to take the integral from 0 to 10, of **r**'(t) to get the length after it moved 10 units along the curve

-Starting point could be position vector?

-Component-wise differentiation may be needed to find the position vector

I have tried these steps but still cannot obtain a final answer because I'm not sure what to do. Any guidance or help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Arc length is the integral of $\|\mathbf r'(t)\|$, not $\mathbf r'(t)$. Start by computing this. You might find that the problem becomes very simple after that.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I forgot to show the magnitude sign. Anyways, I calculated
 ∥r′(t)∥ and got 5. Then I took the integral which is of course 5t. I'm kind of stuck here now, I tried the integral from 0 to 10 as well but it didn't give me what I'm looking for. How do I get the position vector now?

Comment: You have $5t$ for the distance traveled in time $t$. Solve for $t$ and substitute back into $\mathbf r(t)$.

Comment: since it moved 10 units along the curve, would I have to do 10=5t... t=2? and plug 2 in r?

Comment: That’s it exactly.